# adding a item in listBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

My requirement is if an item(text from textBox) already present in the listbox then simply don't add.But the else part I can't use in my foreach loop to add item.here is my code.Help me how I can add an item if a item is not present in the listbox.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (RadioButton1.Checked)
      {
            if (ListBox1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
                Label2.Text = "<b style='color:green'> item updated in the listbox </b>";
            }
            else 
            {
                foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
                {
                    if (li.Text.ToUpper() == TextBox1.Text.ToUpper())
                    {
                        Label2.Text = "<b style='color:red'> access denied 
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply :

```
ListItem item = new ListItem(TextBox1.Text);

if (!ListBox1.Items.Contains(item))
{
//Add item here
}
```

Comment: This is showing invalid arguments .. Didn't  work for me.  .   :(

Comment: check my edit, you must use the `Contains` with a ListItem

Comment: It worked. But the problem is I don't want to add duplicates.. suppose I entered "Hello".Then it should not accept "Hello" in any case. So I can't use contains method

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Listbox from **System.Windows.Controls**, Quentin Roger already gave you the right solution. I just tried it out to see
why it isn't working. You can simply test it in another project:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
lb.Items.Add("Test");
bool b = lb.Items.Contains("Test");
```

b will be true.

Sorry, I know this should be in a comment and not in a separate answer, but
I don't have the privilege to write comments.

Comment: It worked. But the problem is I don't want to add duplicates.. suppose I entered "Hello".Then it should not accept "Hello" in any case. So I can't use contains method

Comment: I don't get the problem here, sorry. If you want to check if something isn't in the Listbox, you could simply use "!" before calling contains: if(!lb.Items.Contains("s")) { .. } - in this case "s" isn't in the list, so the whole statement would be true and the program would go into the if-statement. So you could simply write if(!lb.Items.Contains("Test")) { lb.Items.Add("Test"); }. So test will be added, because it isn't in the list.

Comment: It will only check if the item "Test" is present or not.If I'll enter "tEst" or "tesT" then it will accept.. which I want to avoid

Comment: Ahhh... now I get the problem. Just use the .ToLower() function on each string. Well I think you might have to write a comparer-class, but you can also iterate over all Items and ask if Items[0].ToLower().Equals(text.ToLower()), but that would be a bit exaggerated.

Comment: still I'm not able to solve this one .. Can you please write the code or else the logic part .. what should i write ?

Comment: Did your example above even work? The way you are looking for a similar item is right, but you will have to write something like this: foreach(String li in lb.Items) { if(li.ToUpper() == tb.Text.ToUpper()) { ...Label2.Text... } }.

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool status = false;
  if (RadioButton1.Checked)
    {
        if (ListBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
            Label2.Text = "<b style='color:green'> item updated in the listbox </b>";
        }
        else 
        {
            foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (li.Text.ToUpper() == TextBox1.Text.ToUpper())
                {
                    Label2.Text = "<b style='color:red'> access denied </b>";
                    status = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            //ListItem item = new ListItem(TextBox1.Text);
            //if (!ListBox1.Items.Contains(item))
            //{
            //    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
            //    Label2.Text = "<b style='color:green'> item updated in the listbox </b>";
            //}
            if (status == false)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
                Label2.Text = "<b style='color:green'> item updated in the listbox </b>";
            }
        }

    }
```

here is my solution